# Extracting Sub text start with certain word and ends with a certain word

Tags: regex, vba

Would like to use a VBA REGEX to extract from a given text the part number and manufacturer only:

```
BALL BEARING SKF 2209 ETN9/C3 | BALL BEARING SELF ALIGNING SKF 2209 ETN9/C3
SELF ALIGNING BALL BEARING 23222CCK/W33| TIMKEN BEARING;BALL 23222 CCK/W33
```

the output should be `2209 ETN9/C3` and `TIMKEN 23222 CCK/W33`

I tried `^(\bBEARING.+)BALL$` and `^(BEARING)|$`, but it does not work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

does the following do the job ?

```
\d+\s?[A-Z0-9]+\/[A-Z0-9]+
```

Selected matches:
[image]

Tested with [www.regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com)

Comment: i am using this vba functuon

Function RegxStrng(inValue As Variant, hasValue As Variant) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Dim objRegM As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
MyStrng = UCase(inValue.Value)
objRegex.Pattern = hasValue
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    If .test(MyStrng) Then
    Set objRegMC = .Execute(MyStrng)
        For Each objRegM In objRegMC
        RegxStrng = RegxStrng & Chr(32) & objRegM.submatches(0)
        Next
    Else: RegxStrng = False
    End If
End With
End Function

Comment: with this function unfortunately it does not work
Any ideas ?

Comment: Function RegxStrng(inValue As Variant, hasValue As Variant) As String 
Dim objRegex As Object 
Dim objRegMC As Object 
Dim objRegM As Object 
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp") 
MyStrng = UCase(inValue.Value) 
objRegex.Pattern = hasValue 
With objRegex
 .Global = True 
If .test(MyStrng) Then Set objRegMC = .Execute(MyStrng) 
For Each objRegM In objRegMC 
RegxStrng = RegxStrng & Chr(32) & objRegM.submatches(0) 
Next 
Else: RegxStrng = False 
End If 
End With 
End Function

Comment: add this function to your post's body, in a formatted version. But I do not see the regex in the function.

Comment: This regex I posted will not do it ?

Comment: yes
  It works!!!
  I just had to add brackets
  (\d + \s? [A-Z0-9] + \ / [A-Z0-9] +)

  Thank you

Comment: Thank you

Actually I am looking for a general solution to capture any sub-text
 within the text 
In my example for instance to Capture
SKF 2209 ETN9/C3 | BALL BEARING

Comment: you have to determine some precise format for your matches, otherwise there is no way to get one. You saying you want "SKF 2209 ETN9/C3" and "Ball Bearing" leaves me without a clue of what a match for you should look like.